# background-image not working

Tags: asp.net, html, css, background

I have this in my HTML everything works except the background-image: 'images/Header.jpg'; 
Instead I see the grey color in the header but not the image.. I tried removing the grey color but still dont see the image...

```
#outerWrapper #header {
border-bottom: solid 1px #628152; 
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: bold;
line-height: 15px;
height: 115px;
background-color: Grey;
background-image: url('images/Header.jpg');
```

How can I make this work.. please help.. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at your page with [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) for Firefox.  You may not be loading the image properly.  You will also be able to play with the css on the fly if that's your issue.

Answer (score 5):

What is the path of your CSS file and the path of the image?

You must take in account that, when using `url()` in CSS, **the path is relative to CSS file, not to the requested page**.

Imagine you have the following files:

```
/website/index.html
/website/templates/main.css
/website/images/header.jpg
```

than the CSS must be:

```
.style{background-image:url(../images/header.jpg);} /* Noticed "../"? */
```

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the url to '/images/Header.jpg'

Comment: may be hosting doesn't config for static content

Comment: @AlexNguyen : I didn't mean to move the file, but rather the reference to it. Change this: `url('images/Header.jpg');` to this: `url('/images/Header.jpg');`

Comment: That worked for me, thanks @Mark! Ha, the relative-path just needed to be preceded by a `/`.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you need the ' char? And maybe it is case sensitive and you have a mistake in the url..
Maybe `background-image:url(images/header.jpg);`